# Shows db is not defined while inserting data to mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am learning node js and mongoDb. I am trying to insert data using mongoose but while inserting it show error **db is not defined**. i am not able to figure out mistake. I have tried all my solution as i could try as a beginner.

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose"); // require mongoose

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydatabase', {useNewUrlParser: true});

const myConnection = mongoose.connection;

// Create Schema
var employeeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: String,
email: String,
eType: String,
hourRate: Number,
totalHour: Number,
});


employeeSchema.methods.totalSalary = function () {
var total = employee.hourRate * employee.totalHour;
console.log(`total Salary is = ${total}`);
};

var employeeModel = mongoose.model("Employee", employeeSchema);

var employee = new employeeModel({
name: "Akash Jangra",
email: "developer64@gmail.com",
eType: "Hourly",
hourRate: 500,
totalHour: 70,
});

// console.log(employee)
employee.totalSalary();

 myConnection.on('Connect', function(){
console.log('Connected Successfully')
 });

  myConnection.on('disconnect', function(){
console.log('Disconnected')
 })

  myConnection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

  db.once('open', function() {
  // we're connected!
   employee.save(function(err, res) {
    if (err) throw error
    console.log(res)
    myConnection.close()
   })
```

[image: error]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9gfU.png)

[image: mongoDB compass]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're referring to the wrong variable here.

`myConnection.once` should work. You have not declared `db` anywhere in your code.